# How to iterate through a JSON schema and setting all the values to an empty string?

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to iterate through a JSON schema object which have many nested properties.

```
{
    "schema": {
        "type: "object",
        "properties": {
            "nestObj1": {
                "type: "object",
                "properties": {
                    "nestObj12": {
                        "type":string
            "nestObj2": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "nestObj22": {
                        "type": "object",
                        "properties": {
                            "nestObj23": {
                                "type": "string"
    }
}
```

I want to turn the above into this

```
{
    "nestObj1": {
        "nestObj12": ""
    },
    "nestObj2": {
        "nestObj22": {
            "nestObj23": ""
        }
    }
}
```

I feel like recursion would be best to do this, but I just can't think of how to recursively go through the entire thing and creating key value as we go along. nestObj will stop when the type is a string and will continue if it is an object type.

Comment: what format are the keys in? is there something that is common that we can use or is it completely dynamic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do what you are wanting recursion is definitely a good way to do. Heres an example that would work with what you have provided

```js
function generateDataFromSchema(schema) {
  if (!schema) { return }

  if (schema.type === 'string') {
    return ''
  }

  const parsedData = {}
  
  Object.keys(schema.properties).forEach( (item) => {
    parsedData[item] = generateDataFromSchema(schema.properties[item])
  })

  return parsedData
}

const dataToParse = {
  schema: {
    type: 'object',
    properties: {
      nestObj1: {
        type: 'object',
        properties: {
          nestObj12: {
            type: 'string'
          }
        }
      },
      nestObj2: {
        type: 'object',
        properties: {
          nestObj22: {
            type: 'object',
            properties: {
              nestObj23: {
                type: 'string'
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
};

console.log(generateDataFromSchema(dataToParse.schema))
```

Comment: @AceSok happy to help! if you need help understanding anything I can explain it. When you're able to if you could click the checkmark to mark the question as resolved that would be greatly appreciated! :)